How do you hide "BlacklistedToken" and "OutstandingToken" from django admin panel?
After I added the JWT functionality to my REST apis built using djangorestframework, I have noticed these two models (BlacklistedToken and OutstandingToken) on my django admin panel that in the django admin panel, which I want to hide:

I already checked this question:
Hide the token table from the admin panel in Django REST Framework
Which is quite similar to the issue I have, except that since I'm using djangorestframework-simplejwt I did the following on my admins.py:
from django.contrib import admin

from rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist.models import (
    BlacklistedToken,
    OutstandingToken,
)

# Unregister the blacklisted and outstanding token models
admin.site.unregister(BlacklistedToken)
admin.site.unregister(OutstandingToken)


and I get:
File "/home/couzhei/code/Map-of-defect/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 153, in unregister
    raise NotRegistered("The model %s is not registered" % model.__name__)
django.contrib.admin.exceptions.NotRegistered: The model BlacklistedToken is not registered

I even intentionally register and then unregister them, but it only removes the above exception, not hiding them. Any ideas would be appreciated.

There was no error in my django project.
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
'authentication',
'test',
]

# myapp.admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist.models import BlacklistedToken, OutstandingToken


admin.site.unregister(BlacklistedToken)
admin.site.unregister(OutstandingToken)

The unregister method causes a NotRegistered error if the class you want to delete does not exist in the _registry property of the AdminSite class object.
class AdminSite:
    ...
    def unregister(self, model_or_iterable):
    """
    Unregister the given model(s).

    If a model isn't already registered, raise NotRegistered.
    """
    if isinstance(model_or_iterable, ModelBase):
        model_or_iterable = [model_or_iterable]
    for model in model_or_iterable:
        if model not in self._registry:
            raise NotRegistered("The model %s is not registered" % model.__name__)
        del self._registry[model]
    ...

Simply an error that occurs when you try to delete something that has not yet been registered.
The register is associated with the order of INSTALLED_APPS(settings.py).
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'authentication',
'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
'test',
]

Unlike before, an error occurs when the app authentication containing the code to perform admin.site.unregister (BlacklistedToken) is placed above 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'.
Because the admin in the authentication(myapp) app may be performed before the admin 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist' admin to delete it before registering it.
# djangorestframework-simplejwt/rest_framework_simplejwt/token_blacklist/admin.py
...
admin.site.register(OutstandingToken, OutstandingTokenAdmin)
...
admin.site.register(BlacklistedToken, BlacklistedTokenAdmin)
...

I wonder if an error has occurred because of this problem.

Thanks man! Actually you just made me wonder around my settings.py and I found that   I placed an account app containing account/admin.py just higher than the "rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist" which was actually responsible for registering those models, in the first place! and my code was just unregistering models which haven't been registered yet!

You need to handle exception NotRegistered of models like this
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import NotRegistered

from rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist.models import (
    BlacklistedToken,
    OutstandingToken,
)

# Unregister the blacklisted and outstanding token models if they are registered
models_to_unregister = [BlacklistedToken, OutstandingToken]

for model in models_to_unregister:
    try:
        admin.site.unregister(model)
    except NotRegistered:
        pass


Although I knew early on that your code is just handling that exception and not solving the issue, I still gave it a try. I am still grateful for your effort, but the problem still persists.
